# Embedding executable in Java application

Tags: java, jar, executable, exe

How can I embed binary file (executable, to be exact) in Java application? Is there a way to read a file during compile time, or do I have to copy hexadecimal dump into source code of the application ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jar files are zip files with extra meta-data.  You can easily embed an exe-file in your jarfile directly.

You cannot easily have Windows *execute* the EXE-file inside your zip-file, but you can read it from your classpath resource and write it to a temporary file with an ".exe"-suffix, and then execute that.